# How to add a click method inside of element with click method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose I have:

```
   <div id="outer" onclick="thingsHappen()">
      <div id="inner"></div>
   </div>
```

When I click on *outer* or *inner* div, thingsHappen() is executed. That is obvious.

Now I have got a need to define a different method for the *inner* div. 
For example

```
$("#inner").click(function() {
    doThings();
});
```

When I click on *inner* both thingsHappen() and doThings() executes.
How do I execute doThings() when I click on inner div without executing thingsHappen()?

I tried to unbind click method from #inner, but it did not work. 
PS. I cannot change the structure of HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Stop the propagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) of the event:

```
$("#inner").click(function(e) {
    doThings();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/QNt76/

JavaScript events bubble up the DOM tree unless you stop them from propagating. This is what was causing the parent event handler to get notified.

Answer (score 1):

You want `Event.stopPropagation()`:

```
$("#inner").click(function(e) {
    doThings();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: `return false` has not exactly the same effect as `event.stopPropagation` method, thus it is considered harmful. See http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/ for more explanations

Comment: No, they do not have the same effect. `return false` prevents the default action of the link from occurring, stops propagation of the event, and returns from the event handling function immediately.

Comment: Oh, whoops, didn't know that! Thanks for the callout, guys, fixing.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#inner").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    doThings();
});​
```

Comment: Yes, because of jQuery has been designed in such a way.

Answer (score 0):

You have to stop the propagation to the Document Tree:

```
$("#inner").click(function(event) {
    doThings();
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

> Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

Answer (score 0):

Events pertaining to a child element bubble up to parent elements in the DOM unless propagation is stopped like so:

```
$("#inner").click(function(event) {
    doThings();
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Here is a good read on capturing/bubbling and Javascript events. http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is stop the event (click) from "bubbling" up.  In this case, you would want to stop the propagation of the event in the bubbling phase.  If you are using jquery, you can use this function:

**HTML**

```
<div id="outer" onclick="thingsHappenOuter()"> 
    <div id="inner">
    </div> 
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$("#inner").click(function(event) {       
    event.stopPropagation();
    // do something     
});
```

SEE:  http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/ for more information.